# Why do Russians call a joke a stake (прикол)?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, этимология, история-языка, сленг

In modern Russian, **прикол** is a very frequently used word and means a joke, a funny incident, or just anything funny, but the original meaning of this word is very different: a stake to which a ship, a tent, or an animal is tied. At least, only such a definition is given in *Dictionary of Church Slavonic and Russian composed by the Second Department of the Imperial Academy of Sciences*, published in 1847. Russians still occasionally use this word in its original meaning, e.g., in the idiomatic phrase **корабль стоит на приколе** (the ship is laid up). The composition of this word is very simple: **кол** is the root of the word, means a stake, and is related to the verb **колоть** (to pierce, stub, or cut), and **при** is a prefix similar to the English prefix *in*, so the composition of **прикол** contains nothing related to joking, which means that the modern meaning is figurative or derived.

My question: How did **прикол**, originally meaning a stake, came to mean a joke? In other words, what is the logical connection between the modern and original meanings of **прикол**?

I did some research on the Internet and saw a hypothesis that the modern meaning stems from a criminal jargon, but it is unclear as to exactly how Russian criminals saw a connection between a stake and a joke. Might the connection be that they considered it funny to stab someone with a stake or a knife?

Comment: There seem to be some parallels with the english word 'jab' which has both the direct physical sense similar to колоть, and also the sense of a joke.

Comment: Also notable is a meaning of [колкий](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) as in caustic, sarcastic. Not sure if it shares origins with прикол but it might.

Comment: `прикол, originally meaning a stake` - this doesn't look right at all. `Прикалывать` would mean `to pin` and `to make fun of`, though you'd find `прикалываться` to be used more often in the 2nd case there. However, when you assume that this should also mean that corresponding nouns in Russian and English could be used for translation - no, this doesn't work.

Comment: @DK. : I strongly disagree with your comment. Here is exact the definition of прикол in the dictionary of 1847 referred to in my post: *Короткий заостренный колъ, вколачиваемый в землю для 
причаленiя къ нему судовъ, прикрепленiя щатровъ и палатокъ или привязыванiя скота* . So прикол did originally mean a stake, as written in my post.

Comment: There is also a word острота which means a satirical joke but literally "sharpness".

Comment: `при is a prefix similar to the English prefix in` I don't think that's the case. `при` is closer to "touch", either physically or conceptually by adding something. See [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-) for some good examples. The prefix for "inside" would be `в`, as in `вколоть`, which means to "inject".

Comment: Also "пркиол" even in this modern sense is not nescessarily a joke. For example: [есть такой прикол, как «отсроченный разрыв селезёнки», когда больному становится ОЧЕНЬ плохо через неделю после травмы](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB)

Comment: @dexgecko : Sure, the Russian prefix *при* and the English prefix *in* are not equivalent, but I cannot find an English prefix that is closer to *при* than *in* is. 
For example, *прилетающий* is translated as *incoming*, so it makes sense to say that the prefixes *при* and *in* are similar to an extent. Or which English prefix is closer to the Russian prefix *при*?

Comment: @Mitsuko - The best equivalent of the Russian prefix _при-_ is the Latin prefix _ad-_ with all of its variants when _d_ is **as**similated to the first consonant of the root:  _a-_ (before sc, sp and st), _ac-_ (before c and q), _af-_ (before f), _ag-_, _al-_, _ap-_, _ar-_, _as-_, or _at-_. **При**ехать – **ar**rive, **при**выкание – **ad**diction, **при**нимать – **ac**cept, **при**креплять – **at**tach, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Just homonyms.**
There's an older word, *подк**о**л* 'joke' together with the verbs *подкол**о**ть* (perf.), *подк**а**лывать* (imp.) 'to play a joke [on smb]', but here 'the joke' is aimed at a person to make laugh of them. *Прик**о**л* is almost the same, only another prefix is kind of showing that the joke is neutral, that is not aimed at/against somebody. That is a mere coincidence that the word sounds like the name of that ship anchorage. The root in all these words is *-кол-* like in *кол**о**ть* 'to prick, to prickle'. The noun *кол* 'a stake, a pointed wooden beam' is connected with the verb, too, the pointed spiky end of the beam makes the connection with the action of the verb.

Comment: Presumably on the other hand it is pure coincidence that *прикол* sounds so appropriately close to English *prickle*.

Comment: @PLL - Yes, sure. That's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: `[on smb]` What does this mean?

Comment: @Clonkex - "smb" means "somebody", it's added there just to show what is usually after that expression in English (like in "Jane likes to play jokes on John"). English uses the preposition 'on' there, but Russian uses no preposition after _подколоть / подкалывать_ (like in _Жанна любит подкалывать Ивана_), these verbs are transitive in Russian, the noun after them is in the accusative case.

Comment: I understood the meaning of the square brackets, but I've never seen "smb" to used to mean "somebody". Why not just write the whole word?

Comment: @Clonkex - It's a typical abbreviation used in dictionaries, grammars, and textbooks I'm used to. Another one of the same kind is "smth" for "something". Now after googling I see both of them most probably originated from the Soviet tradition of teaching English as a foreign language. Sorry, I didn't know they are that limited culturally. :)

Answer (score 9):

Those words are definitely related. The thing is that the relation is not direct.

Let's start with колоть. It has two major meanings – to chop (when talking about wood), and to prick. The word кол derives from the first meaning, as it's a piece of wood that's chopped up to become pointy.

Now about прикол, the "stake to tie something to" comes from кол and therefore from колоть (to chop), and the "joke" comes from подкалывать (to pique smb with a joke), which also comes from колоть, but from "to prick" meaning.

As of why колоть means both to prick and to chop and if those are homonyms, or just different meanings of the same word – I do not know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way, reading your answer, I realized I had a totally wrong impression as to why a stake is called **кол**. I had thought that you call a stake **кол** because you can **колоть** with it :) And now you say that you call a stake **кол** because it is made in the process of **колоть**. Wow, the Russian language and its logical connections are tricky!

Answer (score 4):

probably because it all comes from the most ancient joke to "уколоть" someone. Like plant a nail on the seat for someone's ass, so here you go.

Comment: While not very formal, this is quite plausible :)

Answer (score 2):

here is why...
There is old joke to put it on chair to somebody. It's old drawing pin.[image]

Comment: Эта штучка называется "кнопка"

Comment: Да ну? ))) Вы прям мистер очевидность... но вопрос не в том как это называется. А в этимологии слова прикол или подкол. Ну а если быть точнее, то называется это канцелярской кнопкой.

Comment: Ну да! Насчёт "кол" всё ясно... А вот откуда взялась при-ставка "при"? Может быть, от "приколоть бумагу к доске кнопкой"? Поэтому и +1

Comment: вообще-то изначально было "подколоть"... "я его подколол", а вот приколол - это скорее всего потому, что этими кнопками чаще всего прикалывали листы бумаги или ватмана к доскам... вот и вся этимология. а все что дальше сделало с этим словом поколение, которое не в курсе откуда оно возникло изначально, уже не так важно... теперь они приколом называют каждую шутку, или даже свое состояние удивления "глянь - прикол какой", "во!, прикол", "прикольно". Как та деваха (Эллочка Щукина) из 12 стульев... ))

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that, like quite some modern vernacular Russian dictionary, `прикол` is rooted in drug addicts' slang. What it originally meant is altered mental state where your attention is fixed to some object for no particular reason (`прикололо` or `прикольнуло`).

Later on it caught up with general public, where it not only means a joke but anything worth fixing attention on, some unusual circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

The word doesn't translate as joke, it's more like "a situation likely to be amusing". You can say: let's glue all of Ivan's pictures to his ceiling "for the **прикол**". The root is shared with **колоть** which is either to prick(with a needle unless specified) or to split(e.g. firewood). I guess a needle prick is also splitting skin.

The English expression "to **needle** someone, is broadly the same, except that it's a verb and given English nature, likely to be way more subdued than a Russian prikol.